# IllegalArgumentException Base64 to image decoding android string image in Sqlite

Tags: android

```
if (extras != null) {
                photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
                byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
                 decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                imageView_pic.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
```

**calling like this :**

```
dh.insertData("5", "invertorandbettry", t, j, "25.5.2014",
                    decodedByte);
```

this is my code and I want to get the bitmap so that I can store that bitmap in the `localSqlite` database of the camera and gallery but when I try to take a picture from Camera or gallery and after cropping  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64` at this line:

`byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);`

Ideas?

Thanks...

Comment: You should consider not stocking the picture in local database, this is quite heavy if you already saved it in the gallery

Comment: But i want store is local datbase on blob   i have only 10 pic not much

Comment: Are these pictures private to your app or taken by the user ?

Comment: yes its private picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image_str, Base64.DEFAULT);
        decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,
                decodedString.length);
```

Try this code and Enjoy!..............